# Why does Laravel view renders with content duplicated?

Tags: reactjs, laravel

So im doing a Laravel system, using react in my blade files. That said, I have completely removed react and this bug still appears leading me to conclude it is not related.
I have a couple of views, one for list and one for creating/editing. The list view works just fine, the other duplicates the whole section.

Basically instead of rendering Test it does it twice. These are my routes:

```
 Route::prefix('permissions')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', [PermissionController::class, 'index'])->name('admin.permissions');
        Route::get('/{id}', [PermissionController::class, 'update'])->name('admin.permissions.update');
        Route::get('/datatable', [PermissionController::class, 'datatable'])->name('admin.permissions.table');
        Route::get('/get/{id}', [PermissionController::class, 'get'])->name('admin.permission');
 });
```

And this is my view:

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div id="permissionscreate" data-breadcrumbs="{{ App\Utils\Breadcrumbs::current() }}"></div>

@endsection
```

Why does it duplicate this all thing? The browser rendering shows the page twice, one after the other, and when I return the view('my-view-edit') and log it I can clearly see that the content is duplicated here already

As asked, my Controller:

```
class PermissionController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {
        return view('administration.permission.list');
    }

    public function datatable()
    {
        $query = Permission::all();
        return Datatables::of($query)->make();
    }

    public function update()
    {
        return view('administration.permission.update');
    }

    public function get(string $id) {
        return Permission::where('id', $id)->first();
    }
}
```

app layout blade file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="{{ config('app.locale') }}">
<head>

    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    @php
        $last_update = strtotime('2018-10-02');
        $git_log = shell_exec("git log -1 --format=%cd");

        if(!is_null($git_log)) {
            $last_update = strtotime($git_log);
        }
        unset($git_log);
    @endphp

    @stack('fullcalendar')

    <script>
        window.Laravel = {!! json_encode([
            'csrfToken' => csrf_token(),
        ]) !!};
    </script>
</head>
<body>
@include('common.modalOptions')

<div id="wrapper">

    @include('layouts.navigation')

    <div id="page-wrapper" class="gray-bg">

        @include('layouts.topnavbar')

        @translations
        @yield('content')

        @include('layouts.footer')

    </div>

</div>
<!-- End wrapper-->

@section('scripts')
    // I omitted about 300 lines of <script> because of sheer size
    @stack('head')

    <script src="{{ asset("js/script.js?version=$last_update") }}"></script>

@show

<script>
    $(function () {
        optionsEvent();
    });

    function optionsEvent() {
        $(".options").click(function () {
            var t = $(this);
            var url = "<?php echo url('/pri/pritabelas/') ?>";
            console.log(url);
            showModalOptions(url + "/" + t.attr('data-table'), t.attr('data-title'), function (data) {

                    var input = t.closest('.input-group').find('input');
                    input.val(data.val());
                    input.attr('data-value', data.attr('data-value'));
                },
                {
                    data: {
                        columns: t.attr('data-columns').split(",")
                    }
                });
        });
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share the controller code?

Comment: I edited the post to include it

Comment: What does the code for your `layouts.app` look like?

Comment: I added it here, however i ommited some script tags so that it wouldnt be huge